# How do I set shape.fill.userpicture from one shape to another

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping to set the fill property of one shape (where shape 3 contains a user picture) to the fill property of another shape but it doesn't seem possible. Here is my code.

```
Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 5").Fill = Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 3").Fill
```

if also tried.

```
Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 5").Fill.UserPicture = Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 3").Fill.UserPicture
```

Please advise.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`UserPicture` is a method and it seems it is not possible to take the information of shape picture applied with this method.

What I could suggest, which is working in the simple test I made, to go this direction- by calling this two lines:

```
Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 3").PickUp
Sheet1.shapes("Rectangle 5").Apply
```

As a result picture from 'Rectangle 3' will be applied to 'Rectangle 5'. However, some of other properties could be changed too while dimensions are kept.